# Can I draw a map of the UK, split in to counties which work as hyperlinks

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a friend who struggles organising people working around the country for the most appropriate sites in the UK (In the telecommunications sector)

I want to make him a map of the UK where each county works as a hyperlink to a list (This is because I need it to be visual and for him to understand who lives closest to each site, this could also be great, if not better as a postcode map).

I was wondering if it was possible or even if I could find the code online to draw the correct shapes for the hyperlinks, I couldn't find anything on github or any previous questions for somebody who has tried this.

As I am a beginner it would be great if I could make these hyperlinks using HTML (It doesn't need to look pretty, it just needs to be shaped like the UK!)

It would be great to get suggestions as to how I can do this.

Thanks for you time

Comment: I would recommend checking out the google maps API. This will allow you to display a map without having to draw it yourself, and you can also do various other things with it (set markers etc)

Comment: → https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: You may want to take a look here: https://parall.ax/blog/view/2985/tutorial-creating-an-interactive-svg-map

Comment: If you go with the map (as suggested by deceze), there are plenty of generators out there. Just google "imagemap generator". I'd still go with google maps though

Comment: Wow thanks everybody for such quick and helpful advice. Sadly I have tried him with placing markers on Google Maps however it just seems to confuse him for some reason!    Deceze that link seems really helpful and Panepeter thanks I will look for the generators too, that looks lke it will build something perfect for me! Also thanks very much Daniel, that looks like something worth pursuing too, I really like the look of their end product so if I could replicte that with counties or postal code areas it would be perfect!   Once again thanks so much for the great responses :)

Comment: I made you a demo that draw the shape of a county in google map, you can then click this county which will redirect you to the link you specify. I know you just said you don't want google map but it still seems like the fastest way :)

Comment: Gudradain thankyou so much that is so kind of you! I will have a look at all of these this weekend!

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) is the way to go (as mentioned by other).

The idea is that you should build a polygon for each county in the UK, assign a click event to each polygon you just created and finally redirect the user to the link that you want.

I made a JSFiddle that does it for the Avon county in the UK.

https://jsfiddle.net/mpariscl/vmysg6yh/1/

```
$(function() {
  initialize();
});

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.6881171980821, -2.51998453948394);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: 'satellite'
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var county = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: CountyCoordinates(),
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  county.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(county, 'click', function() {
    location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avon_(county)';
  });
}
```

You can then add the missing counties using the coordinate that you will find on this website : http://www.nearby.org.uk/counties/

Answer (score -1):

[Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript) is the way to go here. You could combine these two examples:

1. [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) for looking up the original address
2. [KML layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) For adding the location of his employees as markers so he can see who is closest.

You can generate a KML file by [creating your own map on Google Maps](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024454?hl=en).

It's not really beginners stuff but due to the examples you should be able to get started.

If you want an easier solution you could just [create a map on Google Maps](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024454?hl=en) and add location of employees there. You can share maps and that would probably be a pretty good tool to solve your friends problem.

*Edit* I just saw your comment about Google Maps. You can perhaps make it easier by styling the map a bit and leaving out details that might be confusing. You can use something like [MapStyle](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) for that.